# Table View Controller и переход из ячейки(Navigation Controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Как программно создать в прототипе ячейки кнопку-переход, с возможностью в будущем вернуться(Navigation Controller)?
Есть идея в ячейку поставить UIButton, ей задать тэг и потом манипулировать, но мне кажется это некорректно в этом случаи) Должно быть что-то стандартное для прототипа ячейки как показано на скриншоте

Стоит отметить, что событие нажатия кнопки нужно обрабатывать(буду передавать данные в следующую форму, указывая что показывать)
Создание своеобразного дерева

Создание ячейки:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; // ячейка
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
// Выводим, обращаясь к тэгам
NSError *error = nil;
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
UILabel *firstLabel;
firstLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
firstLabel.text = [namesDepart[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
UILabel *secondLabel;
secondLabel = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
secondLabel.text = @"";
return cell;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте снизу, такое пролистывание не срабатывает, можно указать Initial View Controller для Navigator Controller и тогда будет работать push, однако нужно, чтобы view controller connect был первым загружаемым экраном, и чтобы он был без навигации

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
ViewControllerSecondTable *viewControllerSecondTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerSecondTable"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerSecondTable animated:YES];
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно уточнить, почему именно такой порядок переходов экранов? Если дело в navigation bar на первом экране, то его можно просто прятать при инициализации экрана (при необходимости снова показать) и сделать обычную навигацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нативный метод обработки нажатия на ячейку:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath { ... }
```

И внутри данного метода делаете `push` на нужный Вам контроллер:

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];     
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: внес вправку в вопрос, из за сложности соединений(скриншот с пояснением, почему нужно так), push не срабатывает

Comment: Соедините Ваш Table controller и Second controller в storyboard и выбирите нужный тип соединения.